# Memory used and Time Taken by external process invoked using ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, processbuilder

I searched stackoverflow for this question but i did not got any useful answer. I want to get the memory used and time taken by the external process which in being invoked by the ProcessBuilder in Java. If the process exceeds a time limit/memory limit then i need to kill it.

To calculate the time taken by the process I am using the following code:

```
   process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
starttTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     flag=false;
        while (flag != true) {
                    try { 
                        returnValue = process.exitValue();
                        flag = true;
                        if (returnValue != 0) {
                            System.out.println("Abnormal termination");
                        } else {
                           System.out.println("Normal termination");
                        }
                        System.out.println("Done");

                    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
                    }

                    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (currentTime - startTime > timeLimitInMilli) {
                        System.out.println("process exceeding time limit");
                        break;
                    }

              }
```

But this method of calculating the time is slow. Is there any faster method of doing the same. Also, I am unable to get the memory used by the process. How can I get it ?

Also, this code is being used by multiple threads that means more than one process is being invoked at a time by different threads.

Comment: Java does not provide process auditing.  That is at best done by OS.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23275/how-to-check-which-limit-was-exceeded-process-terminated-because-of-ulimit may give some ideas.

Comment: The method of calculating time doesn't look particularly slow. However, the check for exceeding the time limit will only run once the process has finished, since this thread waits in `process.exitValue()`.

Comment: @fd. : `procedd.exitValue()` will not wait, but throw `IllegalThreadStateException` as long as process is running. So the code will run the loop continuously.

Comment: @ konsumverweigerer: You are correct, I read the wrong bit of the doc (for `waitFor()` which is just above `exitValue()`) -- my bad!

Comment: This does mean the loop will spin, it should probably `Thread.sleep(..)` or block for a bit so that it doesn't use too much CPU.

Comment: More efficiently would be to add a `Thread.sleep(<millis_you_are_willing_to_wait>)` in the loop and `process.destroy()` the subprocess when the lime limit is exceeded.

Comment: @konsumverweigerer Sounds fine, assuming you don't also want to perform some other checks regularly (like call something to check memory usage.)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to run a wrapper script instead of running the command directly. The purpose of the script would be to check the execution time and memory usage (using OS utilities) and return an error code to indicate any problems.

Alternatively, you could use JNI or other OS-specific commands to determine the memory usage of the other process.

If the other process is a JVM or some other program that will report back its memory usage (for example, via an MXBean) then your loop could ask it directly to report memory usage.

Comment: Can you please provide me with more explaination or provide some good links from where I can study these things, also Thread.sleep(...) is fine when i don't want to calculate the time for which the process ran, but it will not help me to calculate the exact time. It will just let me know if the process is still running or has finished meanwhile the sleep time.